# database connection using struts 

Tags: struts

Please, tell me how can i connect to mysql database using  struts.

Answer (score 1):

[Hibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/) let you map java classes to database tables. In J2EE projects Hibernate is associate to the persistence layer.

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181847/struts-hibernate), i've written some more information about Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

write the below code in the struts-config.xml file

```
<data-sources>
<data-source type="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <set-property property="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <set-property property="url" value="jdbc:mysql://hostname:3306/databasename" />
        <set-property property="username" value="username" />
    <set-property property="password" value="password" />
</data-source>
```

and add the mysql connection jar file in project.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [full tutorial](http://cwiki.apache.org/S2WIKI/struts-2-spring-2-jpa-ajax.html) on the [Struts 2 wiki](http://cwiki.apache.org/S2WIKI/home.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use normal JBDC also. For that you just need to have database driver. below is sample code to connect to mysql database.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = null;
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/dbname","username", "password");
conn.close();
```

get a MySQL JDBC driver from here [download from mysql official page](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)